# How can I have a fancybox-like-popup on body load but with cookie for not continusly loading on reload?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello how can I have a popup box like fancybox but to be appeared only one time per visitor based on a cookie?

Thank you for ideas and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could have [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) as you seem like it (me too by the way) along with a [jquery cookie plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/). So you would check if the user has a cookie and if not show the fancybox, otherwise set the cookie so that if the same user reloads the page there is no *fancy* stuff happening.

Comment: @Mairy, look at the documentation: http://fancybox.net/blog and especially at section number `6. Start FancyBox on page load`.